# Standard node.js metrics?

Tags: node.js, monitoring, metrics

Are there any standard metrics publishing packages for node.js?  I'm not asking about general metrics libraries, but rather packages that produce a specific set of metrics (e.g. http QPS, runtime memory usage, gc stats, etc...)
If you wanted to offer a monitoring service for node.js users, what would you monitor?

Comment: Have you tried new relic? http://newrelic.com/nodejs

Comment: @EdwardKnowles, Thanks, I've looked at them briefly.  But to be clear, I'm not looking for a monitoring solution, I'm wondering if there are a standard set of metrics that one might monitor.
Do you know if newrelic provides a documented moniotoring interface to node apps? (I couldn't find information to that effect on their site).

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Node Application Metrics ('[appmetrics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appmetrics)') provides what your looking for. This is a module that provides a set of metrics about a running Node.js process, rather than a monitoring solution in itself.

In version 1.0.2 is provides the following data types:

- Environment
- CPU
- Memory
- GC
- Function profiling
- HTTP
- MySQL
- MongoDB
- Request tracking
- Function trace

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics`.   It's about as standard as you get for 2024.   Most metrics aggregators, both commercial and open-source, support ingesting metrics from opentelemetry now.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of any package that provides all of that metrics but you can collect most using very popular libraries like [pidusage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pidusage) for process related metrics, mongodb driver to retrieve mongo stats, etc

You may [read here (my post, bullet 12)](http://goldbergyoni.com/checklist-best-practice-of-node-js-in-production/) about memory profiling